# How to get process "type" (App, Background Process, or Windows Process)

Tags: c#, windows, types, process, diagnostics

I am trying to get a list of all processes which are of the type "app" (as opposed to "Background Process" or "Windows Process").

[image: "App" type]

Unfortunately, although I know that...

```
var processList = Process.GetProcesses();
```

will get me a list of all processes running on the system, I am at a loss for how to get the 'type' of the process. 'Process' does have a method 'GetType', but it doesn't seem to refer to the "type" that I'm referring to, and that TaskManager refers to in the above image.

Does anyone know how I can get this value that Task Manager refers to as "type" into a variable for a given process?

Note: C#.

Comment: I don't know for sure the logic Windows 8 Task Manager uses to categorize processes. You'd probably have to ask Raymond Chen. :) But I suspect that it's looking at whether the process has at least one UI window. You won't get that from the `Process` class, but you can correlate information about windows that are present and the processes that own them.

Comment: Maybe that type bears on the process' `MainWindowHandle` property; not sure of proper using of the `Refresh` [method](http://stackoverflow.com/a/16185802/3439404). In any case: a process has a main window associated with it only if the process has a graphical interface, otherwise the `MainWindowHandle` value is zero.

Answer (score 6):

I couldn't find the exact answer, but I found what helps me. You need to use the ***MainWindowHandle*** property of class **Process**.

```
var processes = Process.GetProcesses().Where(pr => pr.MainWindowHandle != IntPtr.Zero);

foreach (Process proc in processes)
    Console.WriteLine(proc.ProcessName);
```

**Warning**

If you try to get ***proc.MainModule.FileName*** you may see the Win32Exception exception. To avoid this issue I compile my project as x64 (your project -> properties -> Build -> Platform target -> x64).

Answer (score 0):

Meet the same question, and find an answer in the follow link:https://devblogs.microsoft.com/oldnewthing/20171219-00/?p=97606

- If the process has a visible window, then Task Manager calls it an “App”.
- If the process is [marked as critical](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/processthreadsapi/nf-processthreadsapi-isprocesscritical?redirectedfrom=MSDN), then Task Manager calls it a “Windows Process”.
- Otherwise, Task Manager calls it a “Background Process”.