# How to start a process and set its main window as a child window of my app

Tags: c#, setparent, managementeventwatcher

I am starting a new process from my c# application.

After the process created I set its main window as a child of my app window using the **ManagementEventWatcher** and **SetParent**.

The problem is that when I write in my query *WITHIN  2* every thing works fine, except that I wait to long.
When I write *WITHIN  1* the MainWindowHandle of the started process not created yet when the event *EventArrived* fired.

Is there any good way to wait for the handle to be created except using timer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the MSDN documentation for [**`Process.MainWindowHandle`**](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.process.mainwindowhandle(v=vs.110).aspx) you can use the [**`Process.WaitForInputIdle()`**](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/kcdbkyt4(v=vs.110).aspx) method in order to *"allow the process to finish starting, ensuring that the main window handle has been created."*

Depending on how long it takes the process to finish starting you might want to wait for it in a thread, or else your UI might freeze.

Either way just go ahead and wait:

```
yourProcess.WaitForInputIdle();
//Do your stuff with the MainWindowHandle.
```

---

Another option would be to run your code in a thread and loop until `MainWindowHandle` is not zero. To avoid getting into an infinite loop you could add some sort of timeout.

```
int timeout = 10000; //10 seconds.
while (yourProcess.MainWindowHandle == IntPtr.Zero && timeout > 0)
{
    yourProcess.Refresh();
    System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(250); //Wait 0.25 seconds.
    timeout -= 250;
}

if (yourProcess.MainWindowHandle == IntPtr.Zero)
{
    //Timed out, process still has no window.
    return; //Do not continue execution.
}

//The rest of your code here.
```

Comment: it doesn't work for me. it is just pass the wait before the mainWindowHandle created. Using `while (myProcess.MainindowHandle == IntPtr.Zero) { }` lead to infinite loop.

Comment: @e.s : Hmm... I'll do some testing around the subject and see what I come up with.

Comment: @e.s : I have now ran tests with both `Process.WaitForInputIdle()` and the `while`-loop, and both worked completely fine! Even without using threads. If it doesn't work for you, then perhaps the process that's starting doesn't have a main window?

Comment: @e.s : Also see this answer: http://stackoverflow.com/a/16185802/3740093 -- Perhaps you need to call `Process.Refresh()` every now and then in your loop?

Comment: the **Process.Refresh()** inside the loop works for me. But I'am afraid to get into infinity loop. Thanks A lot.

Comment: @e.s : You will only get an infinite loop if `MainWindowHandle` never changes from `IntPtr.Zero`, that is, when the process actually has no window. Create a thread and make a timeout to stop it from getting into an infinite loop.